# how to send a file from php to python

Tags: php, python

Is this the right way to send a file from php controller to a python script

```
    public function Upload(Request $request) {          
        shell_exec("python ../../../../../../Users/Faizan/Desktop/work/myscript.py $request->file('uupload')");    
}
```

i have been able to send a string this way but my question is this can i send a file through this and how can i check it if it is passed.
Here is my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the location of file as a string and fetch file at python using the path.

Or send over sockets [Client Server application with PHP and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008396/client-server-application-with-php-and-python)